# AMD GPU only available when logged in

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, pyopencl

i am running a AMD Radeon GPU on Linux with installed AMD SDK for OpenCL (latest version).

Now, when I am not logged in via GDM (when main X server is not running), there is no AMD GPU available, so all the computation will be done by CPU.
When I am logged in via GDM (the main x server is running), the GPUs appear when I list them using the following program in python (only core part displayed):

```
for platform in cl.get_platforms():
    for device in platform.get_devices():
        print("===============================================================")
        print("Platform name:", platform.name)
        print("Platform profile:", platform.profile)
        print("Platform vendor:", platform.vendor)
        print("Platform version:", platform.version)
        print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Device name:", device.name)
        print("Device type:", cl.device_type.to_string(device.type))
        print("Device memory: ", device.global_mem_size//1024//1024, 'MB')
        print("Device max clock speed:", device.max_clock_frequency, 'MHz')
        print("Device compute units:", device.max_compute_units)
```

My question ist, whether it is possible to use AMD GPUs without the X server (fglrx) running? Is there any way to do that?

John

Answer (score 1):

See [this tutorial](http://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo#Running_OpenCL_code_remotely_on_AMD_GPUs_.28via_SSH.29) on how to get access to the X server even when logged in remotely.